# ExtJS TabPanel SetActiveTab Reverting back to 0

Tags: extjs, extjs-mvc

I have a tabpanel where you can click a button to create new tabs. When the button is click it creates the new tab not issue, but when I call setActiveTab it appears to do nothing. When I stepped through it in Chrome I can see it is actually changing the tab to the specified one but then switching it back to the original. Any help would be great. Here is the code:

Tab control:

```
{
                xtype:'tabpanel',
                itemId:'tabctr1',
                width:785,
                hidden:true,
                items:[
                    { iconCls: 'btn-NewTab', tabConfig: { listeners: { click: btnAddSensor_Click } } }
                ]
            }
```

Click Event:

```
function btnAddSensor_Click(sender,e,eOpts)
{
//Local Variable Declaration
var parent = sender.up('tabpanel');

if (parent !== null && parent !== undefined)
{
    var newTab = parent.add({
        title: parent.items.length,
        layout: 'vbox', 
        width:785, 
        margin:'5 0 0 0',
        items:[

                ]
            }
        ]
    });

    parent.setActiveTab(newTab);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appaers to be a timing issue and I was able to resolve using:

```
Ext.Function.defer(function(p){ p.setActiveTab((parent.items.getCount()-1)); }, 1000, this, [parent]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your first tab is essentially a button... I'm not exactly sure why it's the issue, but it works if you set it as a button.  Take a look at my [Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/lnl).  And the corresponding code:

```
var parent = Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
  width: 785,
  height: 400,
  buttons: [{
    text: 'Add Tab',
    listeners: {
      click: btnAddSensor_Click
    }
  }]
});
function btnAddSensor_Click(sender,e,eOpts) {            
  if (parent !== null && parent !== undefined) {
    var newTab = parent.add({
      title: parent.items.length,
      layout: 'vbox',
      margin:'5 0 0 0',
      items: [{
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'hello ' + parent.items.length
      }]
    });

    parent.setActiveTab(newTab);
  }
}
```

And I think I just realized why the issue is there... when you click your tab to add a new tab, Ext wants to make sure the clicked tab is being set, so it's firing `setActiveTab`, but you're also calling `setActiveTab` in your click function, so it's essentially being fired twice... meaning your programmatic way is being called first, so it's losing out.